# What are the dimension of a $(n \times m) \times p$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am currently reading a math book about Model predictive control which involves a lot of linear algebra. The book mentions:

> $l$ is an $(N×n)×m$ matrix formed by $N$ $m×m$ identity matrices

Personnaly, I feel like there are several ways to interpret this sentence: are we suppose to concatenante the $N \times n$ matrices as column or rows ?

Assuming that $N =2$, $n = 2$ and $m = 3$, how should I interpret the statement ? What are the resulting matrix's dimensions ?

Comment: This is impossible to tell from the limited context. All I can suggest is to dig deeper into the book itself; perhaps they define what they mean beforehand, or perhaps what they mean will become clear from the later context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m = 3$ then an $m\times m$ identity matrix is
$$I_m = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

If $N = 2$ then if we make a "column" of matrices with one copy of $I_m$ in each "row", we get
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

This matrix has $Nm$ rows and $m$ columns, so it is an $(Nm)\times m$ matrix.

I don't see anywhere to introduce an independent variable $n.$

See if this matches the way the book uses the so-called
"$(N \times n) \times m$" matrix.

Comment: So I checked with my textbook and I think it is indeed the right way to understand thr sentence.